# JOptionPane.showMessage hangs in RMI application

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, rmi, joptionpane

I am implementing a client-server application with RMI and I get a blank message dialog when I catch an exception in the client side. The code is as follows:

In the update method of an observer:

```
@Override
public void actualizar(ObservableRemoto origen, Serializable param) throws RemoteException {
if (param.equals(Modelo.EVENTO_CHECK_SALDOS)){
        try {
            jugador = mesa.buscarJugador(jugador.getJugador());
            jugador.expulsado();
        } catch (InvalidUserActionException ex) {
            vista.cerrarVentana(ex.getMessage());
            salirDeMesa();
        } 
    }
```

The `cerrarVentana()` method in the View of this controller:

```
@Override
public void cerrarVentana(String msj) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, msj);
    dispose();
}
```

When this method is called, the message dialog is shown blank and hangs. On the other side, when i call `JOptionPane` with other method that is triggered in the same view as it is shown, the `JOptionPane` works just fine. It's coded as following in the same view as `cerrarVentana()`:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    BotonRuleta origen = (BotonRuleta)e.getSource();
    Numero n = origen.getNumero();
    try{
        String sMonto = top.obtenerApuesta();
        controlador.apostar("Pleno " + n.getValor(), n, sMonto); // change heree
        controlador.mostrarNum();

    } catch (RemoteException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(VistaMesaV1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    catch (InvalidUserActionException ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I'm wondering what the difference between those two JOptionPane calls is, besides one being called from the controller and the other one from the view, and how can I fix the first example.
One thing to note is that in the previous version of this app, when I hadn't implemented RMI yet, both of these methods worked fine.

Comment: Remote methods should not perform GUI operations. Something very odd here.

Comment: It's not the remote object that calls directly for this display, I'm not sure if that helps. Anyway, i know now that this problem doesn't appear when ran in another PC. It is kind of more unsettling even.

Comment: One likely difference is that one JOptionPane, the one called from the Actionlistener is guaranteed to be called from the Swing event thread, while the other has a high likelihood of this not occurring. Queue the other JOptionPane onto the Swing event thread, the EDT, make sure that all long-running calls are made **off** of this same thread, and then I will bet you that your problems are solved.